# He has "a ways" to go?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I've always wondered why this phrasing is used in English:

> He has a ways to go.

A ways? "A" ways? Why isn't it:

> He has a way to go.

? Or:

> He has some way to go.

? It really sounds odd to me, every time I hear it.

Comment: It would sound odd to me too (as a British English speaker)!

Comment: Me too, I would say "He has some way to go" or "He has a long way to go."

Comment: It's American English colloquial usage.

Comment: Final S on some words is common. _Toward(s), beside(s), a way(s)_, etc. Always on a common function word.